# Solving Windows 10 "Activation permission for the COM Server application"

Tags: windows-10, security, event-log, event-viewer

On a clean genuine Windows 10 installation, the Event Viewer throws one of these errors every 2-5 minutes:

> The application-specific permission settings do not grant Local
>   Activation permission for the COM Server application with CLSID 
>   {D63B10C5-BB46-4990-A94F-E40B9D520160}  and APPID 
>   {9CA88EE3-ACB7-47C8-AFC4-AB702511C276}  to the user
>   DESKTOP-0HBV05A\lyell SID
>   (S-1-5-21-1841861507-3436430764-2759789522-1002) from address
>   LocalHost (Using LRPC) running in the application container
>   Unavailable SID (Unavailable). This security permission can be
>   modified using the Component Services administrative tool.

How can I determine which application is involved, and potentially resolve the error?  The matching registry entry is:

[image: 9CA88EE3-ACB7-47C8-AFC4-AB702511C276 Windows 10 Registry]